# POST API does not give any result or error on being called using HTTPClient in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages

I have an API made in .NET which I am trying to call in my frontend.

The JSON is being generated just fine but the API itself is not being called at all from the cs file code.

```
 public async void createTransaction(String e)
    {
            Transaction t = new Transaction();
            t.EmployeeEmail=e;
            t.ManagerEmail="test@test.com";
            t.Request="admin";

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);
            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var url = "http://localhost:5001/ssp/addData";
            using var client = new HttpClient();

            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

            string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

No error is being thrown but the API is not being called also.

But after some time it says TaskCanceledException and I am unable to make any sense of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not at all with code. After hours of debugging found out that the "https" in the API url was required instead of http.

```
 HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
 clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

// Pass the handler to httpclient(from you are calling api)
var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler)
```

After adding this everything started working exactly fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
```

Should be

```
HttpResponseMessage response;

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
}
```

Or

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
// ...
client.Dispose();
```

Comment: Will the function be an async function?

Comment: As long as you declare your Method `async` and use `await` keyword in it, it will run async (without being in some syncronous part of code of course).

Comment: Actually "using var client = new HttpClient();" is c# latest syntactic sugar. It auto disposes these objects when current scope is finished.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, my bad. Shall I delete my answer?